# Java ConcurrentSkipListMap's computeIfAbsent method "applied once atomically"

Tags: java, concurrency

The Javadoc for the `computeIfAbsent` method of `ConcurrentSkipListMap` says that "The function is NOT guaranteed to be applied once atomically only if the value is not present." Could someone please explain to me what "applied once atomically" means?

How `computeIfAbsent` in `ConcurrentSkipListMap` compares to the one in `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: It means there's a possibility of a race condition where two threads run the method for the same key, see that it's absent, and compute a new value. CHM guarantees atomicity, which means if one thread sees it's absent and computes a value, no other thread will simultaneously see it as absent.

Comment: So it's basically not atomic? Then, is there a class in Java that allow O(log n) concurrent insertion which is guaranteed to be atomic?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the ConcurrentSkipListMap sometimes has to redo steps internally when it detects that other threads have made concurrent modifications. Because of this, the function you pass to `computeIfAbsent` might run more than once, and so it shouldn't have any side effects.

I looked at the code and the possibility exists that the function can be called optimistically, and so the result might be discarded.